# Android keep one Bitmap as source for changing hue, contrast, saturation etc

Tags: java, android, android-studio, image-processing, android-bitmap

I am developing a feature in my android app, in which the user will be able to modify bitmap's saturation, hue, contrast, etc using SeekBar. I have written different methods for each processing. This works fine individually but if I change Bitmap's Hue and before calling any other method e.g saturation, I want to retain the bitmap with applied hue progress and so on. Users should be able to see the original bitmap if the progress is set to default.

For example,
If I change Bitmap's Hue value to 200. Now if I want to edit saturation the new bitmap for saturation should be with applied hue. And if I reset saturation and hue progress to default, then the user should be able to see original bitmap colors.

I have tried many methods to achieve this behavior e.g copying pixels before each method call but that did not help. Currently, I am just copying pixels of the modified bitmap to an original bitmap on user click for each bitmap processing type but that does not change the bitmap to original colors if I reset all the values. Please see my code.

I hope this will help in understanding the problem.

```
private Bitmap wallpaper, modifiedWallpaper;
private ImageView imageView;
private ImageButton contrast;
private ImageButton hue;
private ImageButton saturation;
private float contrastProgress;
private float hueProgress;
private float satProgress;
private boolean isBlur, isBright, isContrast;
private boolean isHue, isSaturation, isRGB;
private TextView currentMode;
private SeekBar seekBar;
private Paint paint;
private Canvas canvas;
private CardView editor;


@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_customize_wallpaper, container, false);
    imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.wallpaper);
    rgbContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.rgb);
    close = view.findViewById(R.id.close);
    currentMode = view.findViewById(R.id.current_mode);
    seekBar = view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);


    contrast = view.findViewById(R.id.contrast);
    hue = view.findViewById(R.id.hue);
    saturation = view.findViewById(R.id.saturation);

    contrast.setOnClickListener(this);
    hue.setOnClickListener(this);
    saturation.setOnClickListener(this);
    satProgress = 256f;

    loadWallpaper(final String wallpaperUrl);     
    return view;
}


private void loadWallpaper(final String wallpaperUrl) {
    Picasso.get().load(Constants.DOMAIN + wallpaperUrl).into(new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            wallpaper = bitmap; //original loaded
            modifiedWallpaper = wallpaper.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(wallpaper);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
       case R.id.contrast : {
            wallpaper = modifiedWallpaper.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            isBlur = false;
            isBright = false;
            isContrast = true;
            isHue = false;
            isSaturation = false;
            isRGB = false;
            seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rgbContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            changeIconTint();
            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(null);
            seekBar.setMax(90);
            seekBar.setProgress((int) contrastProgress);
            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);
            currentMode.setText("Contrast");
            break;
        }
        case R.id.hue : {
            wallpaper = modifiedWallpaper.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            isBlur = false;
            isBright = false;
            isContrast = false;
            isHue = true;
            isSaturation = false;
            isRGB = false;
            seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rgbContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            changeIconTint();
            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(null);
            seekBar.setMax(180);
            seekBar.setProgress((int) hueProgress);
            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);
            currentMode.setText("Hue");
            break;
        }
        case R.id.saturation : {
            wallpaper = modifiedWallpaper.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            isBlur = false;
            isBright = false;
            isContrast = false;
            isHue = false;
            isSaturation = true;
            isRGB = false;
            seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rgbContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            changeIconTint();
            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(null);
            seekBar.setMax(512);
            seekBar.setProgress((int) satProgress);
            seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChangeListener);
            currentMode.setText("Saturation");
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void changeContrast(float contrastProgress) {
    float cb = this.contrastProgress == 0 ? 0 : -(this.contrastProgress / 1.8f) * 5;
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[]
            {
                    contrastProgress, 0, 0, 0, cb,
                    0, contrastProgress, 0, 0, cb,
                    0, 0, contrastProgress, 0, cb,
                    0, 0, 0, contrastProgress, 0
            });

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
    modifiedWallpaper = wallpaper.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    canvas = new Canvas(modifiedWallpaper);
    canvas.drawBitmap(modifiedWallpaper, 0, 0, paint);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(modifiedWallpaper);
}

private void changeHue() {
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    float hueProgress = cleanValue() / 90f * (float) Math.PI;
    if (hueProgress == 0){
        return;
    }

    float cosVal = (float) Math.cos(hueProgress);
    float sinVal = (float) Math.sin(hueProgress);
    float lumR = 0.213f;
    float lumG = 0.715f;
    float lumB = 0.072f;
    float[] mat = new float[]
            {//logic };
    cm.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
    modifiedWallpaper = wallpaper.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    canvas = new Canvas(modifiedWallpaper);
    canvas.drawBitmap(modifiedWallpaper, 0, 0, paint);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(modifiedWallpaper);
}

private void changeSaturation() {
    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
    colorMatrix.setSaturation(satProgress / 256);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix));
    modifiedWallpaper = wallpaper.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    canvas = new Canvas(modifiedWallpaper);
    canvas.drawBitmap(modifiedWallpaper, 0, 0, paint);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(modifiedWallpaper);
}

private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChangeListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
        if (isContrast) {
            contrastProgress = seekBar.getProgress();
            Log.d("Contrast", "" + (int) contrastProgress);
            changeContrast((float) (seekBar.getProgress() + 10) / 10);
            return;
        }
        if (isHue) {
            hueProgress = seekBar.getProgress();
            Log.d("Hue", "" + (int) hueProgress);
            changeHue();
            return;
        }
        if (isSaturation) {
            satProgress = seekBar.getProgress();
            Log.d("Saturation", "" + (int) satProgress);
            changeSaturation();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not saving state when applying filters. You create a **new** `Paint` with a **new** `ColorMatrix` and a **new** `Bitmap`. This's why one filter overrides the previous one.

There are a few ways to solve this. I think a good first step is separating the "filtering" from the "drawing" functionality. Example: `changeSaturation()` in your code not only changes the saturation but also draws to the screen. 
Here's how I'd do it:

```
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
        if (isContrast) contrast = (float) (seekBar.getProgress() + 10) / 10
        if (isHue) hue = seekBar.getProgress();
        if (isSaturation) saturation = seekBar.getProgress();

        ColorMatrix matrix = calculateColorMatrix(contrast, hue, saturation);
        drawBitmap(matrix);
    }


    private void drawBitmap(ColorMatrix colorMatrix) {
         Paint paint = new Paint();
         paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix));
         modifiedWallpaper = wallpaper.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
         canvas = new Canvas(modifiedWallpaper);
         canvas.drawBitmap(modifiedWallpaper, 0, 0, paint);
         imageView.setImageBitmap(modifiedWallpaper);
    }

    private ColorMatrix calculateColorMatrix(float contrast, hue, saturation) {
        ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();

        // saturation
        colorMatrix.setSaturation(satProgress / 256);

        // hue   
        float cosVal = (float) Math.cos(hueProgress);
        float sinVal = (float) Math.sin(hueProgress);
        float lumR = 0.213f;
        // logic...
        colorMatrix.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(mat));

        //contrast
        // logic...
        colorMatrix.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(new float[]
            {
                    contrastProgress, 0, 0, 0, cb,
                    0, contrastProgress, 0, 0, cb,
                    0, 0, contrastProgress, 0, cb,
                    0, 0, 0, contrastProgress, 0
            }));

        return colorMatrix;
    }
```

That's just one way to do it. Probably the simplest one. If you don't want to create all filters every time the slider moves you can keep three different `matrix` one for each filter and modify only one of them each time.

```java
    ColorMatrix hue = new ColorMatrix();
    ColorMatrix sat = new ColorMatrix();
    ColorMatrix con = new ColorMatrix();

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
        if (isContrast) {
         con = //logic to create contrast matrix
        }
        if (isHue) {
         hue //logic to create hue matrix
        }
        if (isSaturation) {
          //...
          sat.setSaturation(...)
        }


        ColorMatrix matrix = hue.postConcat(sat).postConcat(con);
        drawBitmap(matrix);
    }
```

I haven't tested this code myself, you will likely have to make some changes but I hope this sets you on the right direction!

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot. I am going to implement your logic and will get back to you.

Comment: I tried your logic and it worked as expected. Actually i did't know about .postConcat() method. Thank you so much for your guide and help.